# Submit Ubercart Form Using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal, ubercart

I'm working on a module where I ajaxify the whole checkout process for the user.  What I'm having trouble with is when the user clicks the "review Order" button, I need to submit the order, validate, and then give him the order review page with ajax, and then when he confirms order, i can finally reload.
I can't figure out how to process the thing using ajax.  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post is all you need
Example:

$.post("order.php", { name: "John", cart: "id1,id2,id3" },
   function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });

In the php file you can make a explode function and work out with the ids

say you have a , so in jquery you do: $.

```
("#myform).submit(function(){
    if("#email").val() !== ""){
    AJAX FUNCTION GOES HERE // only will happen if email field is not null
    } else {
    return false; // this ensures the form is not posted in the traditional way
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pedrosath.  But what about the validate functions and submit?  Lol I'm kinda lost can you be more specific?